# PowerShell export AD user x509 certificate and import into ADUC for the user

Tags: powershell, import, export, x509certificate2

What is the best method in PowerShell for exporting a users AD certificate and storing in a data file.

I can get the users certificate:

```
$user = Get-ADuser "tester01"
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 $user.usercertificate
```

I want to export this to a file so that I can import it later to a users AD account using PowerShell.

How do I do this?

Comment: Can you tell us why you need this?

Comment: I need this for certificate management and recovery automation.

Comment: I'm having this exact requirement. I need to export the UserCertificate property to a valid DER file for reading elsewhere. If I make any progress I'll put my own solution here as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PKI issued user certs is on their computer. Just use the certificate drive to get them. Get-PSDrive, Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:. See the help file and the help file examples.

Or use...

> [Export-Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/export-certificate?view=win10-ps)
>
> Module: PKIClient
>
> Exports a certificate from a certificate store into a file.

```
# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Export-Certificate).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Export-Certificate).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Export-Certificate -Examples
# Results
<#
$cert = (Get-ChildItem -Path 
Export-Certificate -Cert $cert -FilePath c:\certs\user.sst -Type SST
$cert = (Get-ChildItem -Path 
Export-Certificate -Cert $cert -FilePath c:\certs\user.cer
$cert = ( Get-ChildItem -Path 
Export-Certificate -Cert $cert -FilePath c:\certs\user.p7b -Type p7b
Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\CurrentUser\my | Export-Certificate ûFilePath 

#>
Get-help -Name Export-Certificate -Full
Get-help -Name Export-Certificate -Online
```

See also:

> https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/CPolydorou.ActiveDirectory/1.7.0/Content/UserCertificates.psm1

Comment: I'll test this out tonight & let you know if it works for my application.